# Clojure warn-on-reflection and type hints

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

In the following code, I am getting a warning on reflection:

```
(ns com.example
  (:import
    [org.apache.commons.cli CommandLine Option Options PosixParser]))

(def *help-option* "help")
(def *host-option* "db-host")

(def *options*
  (doto (Options.)
    (.addOption "?" *help-option* false "Show this usage information")
    (.addOption "h" *host-option* true "Name of the database host")))

(let
  [^CommandLine command-line (.. (PosixParser.)
                               (parse *options* (into-array String args)))

   db-host (.getOptionValue command-line "h")]  ; WARNING HERE ON .getOptionValue
  ; Do stuff with db-host
)
```

I have a type hint on `command-line`. Why the warning?

I am using Clojure 1.2 on OS X 10.6.6 (Apple VM).

I assume that I do **not** get a warning on `(.addOption ...)` because the compiler knows that `(Options.)` is a `org.apache.commons.cli.Options)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Clojure could not determine the method to call because of the `*host-option*` var. If I change the var def to `(def ^String *host-option* "db-host")` it gets rid of the warning.

I updated my question to show the `def` that I actually had in my code.

Answer (score 0):

in clojure 1.2 the return type of every function is object. You may have already thought of this but perhaps the warning is coming from the value returned by the .getOptionValue method of command-line